# Does using multiple imputations for missing data cause the standard deviation to drop?

Tags: r, imputation, standard-deviation

In a recent analysis, I used 20 sets of multiple imputations to account for missing data. I decided to use the following suggestion to calculate the standard deviations of my variables: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229542/multiple-imputation-pooling-mean-and-standard-deviation.

The standard deviations were really low (lower than 0.00 on a scale of 1 - 7!)

My code format is as follows:

```
#sadism variable

QW.sad <- array(dim = m)
UW.sad <- array(dim = m)

for (i in 1:m){
  QW.sad[i] <- mean(complete(Imputed.W.add.mids, i)$sad_tot)
  UW.sad[i] <- var(complete(Imputed.W.add.mids, i)$sad_tot)/nrow(DataW.regress.test)
}

B <-  var(QW.sad)
W.sad.mean <- mean(QW.sad) #mean
W.sad.SD <- mean(UW.sad) + (1 + 1/m) * B #standard deviation
```

Is it simply the case that using multiple imputations causes the standard deviation to drop? (I guess it makes intuitive heuristic sense due to each imputation being similar to each other).

EDIT: I used MICE to impute data

```
Imputed.W <- mice(DataW.regress.test[1:53], maxit=50, seed = 513, m = 20)
```

There were 0.2822456 % and 0.3577555 % missing data in my datasets (I show code only for the 0.3577555 % dataset here).

The standard deviation tested (in the sample item provided was for mean values taken from 9 inputs for individual cases.

I attempted to export a dput file but the code is too long to share in this post.

Comment: Standard deviation _can_ drop during imputation, but it can also increase, depending on your imputation method. I don't see any imputation in your code above, though.

Comment: Greetings! It's difficult to see what imputation was done here to get to this point. Its also usually helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I have updated my post with to hopefully make it more informative.